# PHP not able to connect to MySQL in Ubuntu based custom S2I image

Tags: php, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3

Playing with Openshift origin 3.9 on my custom servers. So far it has been a pleasant experience. I've been building a [custom s2i image](https://github.com/badri/ubuntu-drupal-8-s2i) based on Ubuntu for my LEMP stack.

I'm not able to connect to the MySQL database. I always get an error saying:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) No such file or directory

Here's my PHP code:

```
$mysql_database = getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE");
$mysql_server_name =getenv("MYSQL_HOST");
$mysql_username = getenv("MYSQL_USER");
$mysql_password = getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD");
$mysql_port = getenv("MYSQL_PORT");
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database, $mysql_port);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    die();
}
```

Some observations:

I'm able to connect from MySQL CLI client from inside the pod.

[image]

The same app/code works fine with the official openshift PHP s2i image.

Am I missing anything in my s2i?

Comment: What is the ``MYSQL_HOST`` environment variable set to in the deployment config for your front end? What is the name of the MySQL deployment, or more specifically its service object?

Answer (score 0):

Check your phpinfo() and search for MySQLi extension. If you can't find, that means you do not have the extension installed yet and it needs to install.

try installing from terminal

```
(Ubuntu/Mint) $ sudo apt-get install php(version)-mysql
```

replace (version) with any of your php version number. For example, php7.0 / php7.1, etc.

To check phpinfo(), create a phpinfo.php file which you can access from url with the content

```
<?php
phpinfo()
```

If you have everything and still unable to connect? Try checking your mysql.sock file path.

Open the php.ini file and find this line:

> mysql.default_socket

And make it (know where your mysql.sock located)

> mysql.default_socket = /path/to/mysql.sock

Comment: hi, yes, I have mysql extension installed. You can check the Dockerfile of the corresponding image.

Comment: Accessing MySQL from Terminal and accessing from PHP is totally different story. From your image all i can find is you are using Terminal to access MySQL through MySQL client. You will know the difference if you check the phpinfo() report.

Comment: True :) here's the phpinfo dump for Ubuntu stack(not working) http://ubuntu-lemp.lakshminp.com/info.php and for Centos stack(working) http://centos-lemp.lakshminp.com/info.php

Comment: edit my answer, you may check that mysql.sock i had this same problem once.

Comment: yes, I checked that too. both mysqli.default_socket and pdo_mysql.default_socket point to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.

Comment: In OpenShift the MySQL database would be in completely different pod so it can't be access by local UNIX socket, you have use to a hostname:port to access it as the pod appears as a different host.